# Cypher - Only show node name, not full node in path variable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher I have the following query:

```
MATCH p=(n1 {name: "Node1"})-[r*..6]-(n2 {name: "Node2"})
RETURN p, reduce(cost = 0, x in r | cost + x.cost) AS cost
```

It is working as expected. However, it prints the full n1 node, then the full r relationship (with all its attributes), and then full n2.

What I want instead is to just show the value of the name attribute of n1, the type attribute of r and again the name attribute of n2.

How could this be possible?

Thank you.

Comment: When you return `p`, you are returning a path, which contains nodes and relationships. There's no way to modify the way paths are written to string in result visualisers (such as the Neo4j browser), so you'll need to divide the path into pieces and return only those.

But why are you relying on the printed result? Aren't you running this via an application, which via a driver would be able to consume the path constuctively?

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part of your request is the type attribute of r, as r is a collection of relationships of the path, not a single relationship. We can use EXTRACT to produce a list of relationship types for all relationships in your path. See if this will work for you:

```
MATCH (n1 {name: "Node1"})-[r*..6]-(n2 {name: "Node2"})
RETURN n1.name, EXTRACT(rel in r | TYPE(rel)) as types, n2.name, reduce(cost = 0, x in r | cost + x.cost) AS cost
```

You also seem to be calculating a cost for the path. Have you looked at the shortestPath() function?